# CSS issue with a site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble with this site rendering on small screens. The content divs get pushed down. Does anyone have a recommended solution for this? I've tried a few things and i need a fresh perspective.

http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/wp/rai/

Comment: Tried to set margin/padding on body and html to zero? Html has a margin and a padding of 2% right now.

Comment: I would suggest using the twitter bootstrap method for this kind of websites keeps it lightweight and works like a charm on any device.

Comment: It’d be nice if you could add some more detail and narrow your question down. Currently, to answer your question, folks have to check your site on a mobile device, compare it to the desktop, figure out what you mean by “the content divs get pushed down”, view source to see what you’ve done so far, and then figure out how to fix it. That’s a bit more work than answerers are expected to do on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
#page {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

to :

```
#page {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```